# Is property injection lazy when using Autofac?

Tags: dependency-injection, autofac

If I use Property injection using Autofac then Autofac will resolve it when property will be accessed (using getter method) while constructor injection resolve at the time of objection creation so we can say property injection using Autofac is Lazy.

Please confirm my understanding.

Regards,
Rashi

Comment: Did you actually try anything in the form of a unit test or code before asking this question? Did you look for any existing documentation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Property injection is not lazy. Properties will be set when the service that owns them will be resolved from the container.

Take this example where a class, `Service`, contains a property of type `Dependency`.
We log at different times:

- before the `Service` is resolved from the container
- after the `Service` is resolved from the container
- when accessing the `Dependency` property from the resolved instance of `Service`
- when the `Dependency` property on the `Service` class is being set

```cs
class Program
{
    private static int _logCount = 1;

    public static void Log(string message)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"[{_logCount}]: {message}");
        _logCount += 1;
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var builder = new ContainerBuilder();

        builder
            .RegisterType<Dependency>()
            .AsSelf();

        builder
            .RegisterType<Service>()
            .AsSelf()
            .PropertiesAutowired();

        var container = builder.Build();

        Log("Before resolving Service");
        var service = container.Resolve<Service>();
        Log("After resolving Service");

        Log("Accessing the Dependency property");
        var dependency = service.Dependency;

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}

public class Service
{
    private Dependency _dependency;

    public Dependency Dependency
    {
        get { return _dependency; }
        set {
            Program.Log("Dependency is being injected");
            _dependency = value;
        }
    }
}

public class Dependency
{
}
```

Here is the output:

```
[1]: Before resolving Service
[2]: Dependency is being injected
[3]: After resolving Service
[4]: Accessing the Dependency property
```

Comment: It is important to note that *Property Injection* causes [Temporal Coupling](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/05/24/DesignSmellTemporalCoupling/) and because of that in almost all cases, *Constructor Injection* is a much better pick.